# how to get file extension from filename with wget?

Tags: bash, download, wget

```bash
url = https://website.com/download/media/123
```

This would *maybe* return a file called file.zip or maybe not. So I want to check if the file which gets downloaded ends with `.zip`

Maybe something like this?

```bash
wget $url -P ~/downloads
if [ downloaded file ends with .zip ]
then:
    unzip file.zip
else
    echo "Downloaded file doesn't end with zip!"
fi
```

Comment: I think that in general, an URL such as the one you are specifying, may return several files, or perhaps one HTML file, depending on what the webserver is supposed to do with the link. In any case, you don't know anything on how the filename looks like. I would therefore first empty the download directory, then do the `wget`, and then loop over the files to see what you get there. Testing a filename is done by `[[ FILENAME == PATTERN ]]`, where _PATTERN_ is a glob-pattern. If you prefer, you can also do a `[[ FILENAME =~ REGEX ]]`, where _REGEX_ is a regular expression.

Comment: For the record the fact file do not have `.zip` extension do not meant it is not a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

for a in *
do    
zip=$(printf "${a}" | tail -c 3 | grep -o "zip")

[ -n "${zip}" ] && unzip "${a}"
[ -z "${zip}" ] && echo "File ${a} doesn't end with zip!"
done
```

Comment: I've noticed that there seems to be a taboo against using test statements here.

Comment: You are using a #! for `sh`, but use `[[`, which is not defined for a POSIX shell.

Comment: `file` will always be `123` in your case, so your code will always do a `unzip 123`.

Comment: Still not good. `file` is `123` always. Therefore `zip` will be always empty. Since the logic of your code does not depend on what `wget` is actually doing, you can test your script by prefixing `wget` by `echo`.

Comment: It's messy, but it works now.  He would still be better off dumping into an empty dir tho like you said.

Comment: Instead of `... | tail ... | grep`, you can simpler write  `printf ... | grep -o '[.]zip$'`, and if you would switch to bash, you could do it without a pipe: `grep -o '[.]zip$' <<<"$a"`. However, isn't it possible that `wget`, when invoked with an URL of this kind, returns a full directory structure, instead of just a bunch of files in a flat structure? I don't have much experience with `wget`, but from its man-page, I think it could be the case.

Comment: I don't know which method of listing files in a script I can use, without someone being critical of it.  Ls and find are both taboo; although for the most part they work as long as you don't have whitespace or carriage returns inside the filenames themselves.

Comment: `find` is fine, in particular when used with `-print0`. But in general, if you drop the idea of being POSIX-compliant (and note that the OP tagged the question by _bash_, so he doesn't need a POSIX solution either), you can write it in bash, where you simply do a `shopt -s globstar` and then traverse the whole directory tree by `for a in **`.  If you also do a `shopt -s dotglob`, the `**` even catches hidden files (starting with a dot).

Comment: Actually in zsh, it could be done even simpler (no option settings, just doing a `for a in **(DN)`, but the OP sadly didn't express the wish to have a zsh solution.

Comment: BTW, in bash, I would also do a `shopt -s nullglob`, which would ensure that the loop is skipped if, for whatever reason, no file has been downloaded. The OP did not evaluate the exit code of `wget`, and if he simply plugs in your code into his script, he will get bitten when there are no files.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the idea of get extension and add check via `file` utility:

```
for a in *
do    
zip="${a##*.}"
zip2=$(file $a|grep "Zip archive data"|wc -l)
if [ "zip" = "${zip}" ] || [ "$zip2" -gt 0 ]
then unzip "${a}"
else echo "File ${a} is not zip archive"
fi
done
```